# Azure Powershell - Add-AzureVirtualIP cmdlet not found

Tags: powershell, azure, cloud

I need to add another VIP for my Azure cloud service using Powershell for Azure, since there is no way to do it via the web console. In the past I was able to do it by using the `Add-AzureVirtualIP` command.

However, that command seems to no longer be found since MS switched everything to Azure Resource Manager mode. How can I use this command again, or is there another way to add a VIP to my cloud service?

> Add-AzureVirtualIP : The term 'Add-AzureVirtualIP' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
>   or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and

Comment: which version of your azure powershell, please use this command to check it `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh`

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT I don't get any results when running that command. I am running Windows 10 and have installed the Azure for Powershell tools from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/. Also, I can run other commands such as Login-AzureRMAccount.

Comment: we should install azure powershell first, please browse this page, and install Azure PowerShell https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Azure/3.7.0

Comment: Does it work now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error code, it seems the Azure PowerShell is not loaded correctly.  we can install Azure PowerShell with this command:

`Install-Module -Name Azure`

More information about Azure PowerShell, please refer to the [link](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Azure/3.7.0).